# Can Google Maps guess continent name by given google.maps.LatLng?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does Google Maps API (version 3) offer a method or a feature to simply return what's the name of the continent where a given marker (cords) is located?

If I will pass `52.245049, 21.013124` I would expect to get `europe` (*or maybe a continent code like an integer*).

If I will pass `-27.513125, 153.008325` I would expect to get `australia` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [geoname.org](http://www.geonames.org/) extendedFindNearby returns the continent in the hierachy.

http://api.geonames.org/extendedFindNearby?lat=52.245049&lng=21.013124&username=demo

Returns: `<toponymName>Europe</toponymName>`

http://api.geonames.org/extendedFindNearby?lat=-27.513125&lng=153.008325&username=demo

Returns: `<toponymName>Oceania</toponymName>` (which doesn't seem to be what you want)

And: `<toponymName>Commonwealth of Australia</toponymName>`

The other option would be to create polygons for each of the continents and do a point in polygon analysis to determine the continent.